# get rows without a specific date

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a DB2 table with below structure.

Table has a column for accountno and another column for storing payment date.For the same account,every month multiple/single payments can happeni.e.,there will be multiple entries for the same accountno.

I need to filter out the rows for which payment for a particular month is not present(payment date column).

how can I frame the query for this?

Thank you

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a particular month, you can do:

```
select a.*
from accounts a
where not exists (select 1
                  from payments p
                  where p.paymentdate >= date('2018-03-01') and
                        p.paymentdate < date('2018-04-01');
```

This assumes you have an accounts table with all accounts of interest.

Comment: Thanks.this helps